# WPF - Prism - how to pass parameters to Drawer's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, desktop-application

This is a sample .xaml code that I have, I'm using `DrawerHost` Control from [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:UserControlViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
    
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost IsRightDrawerOpen="{Binding IsDrawerOpen}" OpenMode="Default">
        <materialDesign:DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent>
            <views:RightDrawerView />
        </materialDesign:DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent>
            <!-- Main Content -->
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</UserControl>
```

`RightDrawerViewModel` will be set to be the DataContext of `RightDrawerView` via Prism's `ViewModelLocationProvider`.

**My Question:** When setting `IsDrawerOpen` to true, how can `UserControlViewModel` pass parameters to `RightDrawerViewModel`? as `RightDrawerViewModel` is not called via Prism's methods (`regionManager?.RequestNavigate`, `dialogService?.ShowDialog`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters, you can either `RequestNavigate` instead of setting `IsDrawerOpen` (which needs a region and an custom `RegionAdapter` for the `DrawerHost`) or you create a service known to both the view model that wants to open the drawer and the drawer's view model and put all data there before setting `IsDrawerOpen`.

A third option is to create a new `DrawerViewModel` when you want to open the drawer and assign it to a property on the parent view model and bind it to the drawer's content's data context. Also, remove `IsDrawerOpen` and replace it either with a style or a converter that observe the view model-property on the parent.

I'd go for the first option only if I were forced to go view first, otherwise always prefer the third one. The second's ugly and presented for completeness only.